# вопрос свзяанный с php

Tags: php, mysql

Я новичек в php и у меня такой вопрос. Пользователь вводит форму и на другой странице появляется новый блок со значением из этой формы. Нужно чтобы это было автоматизировано, то есть пользователь ввел форму и программа сама вставила значение формы на другую страницу. У меня есть бд для формы. Спасибо.

Comment: А в чем вопрос автоматизации?

Comment: все примеры есть по ссылке, которую я прикрепил сверху. на одной странице код для добавления в бд, а на другой - код для чтения из БД

Comment: @mepihindeveloper, нужно чтобы когда вводят форму, создавался новый блок со значением из формы и сохранялся, и при последующем вводе создавался новый блок с новым значением формы